# Deinit is it a good practice to implement it on viewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, deinit

I am wondering if it is a good practice to implement a `deinit` on every view controller to check if it is correctly removed when it disappears and avoiding leaking memory?

Comment: Definitely not for just "checking something". Also, for controllers usually makes sense to use their own life cycle methods.

Comment: It is good practice for testing/development/debugging, but not for release. Once you have good "memory hygiene" then memory leaks should become rare/nonexistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, you *don't* have to implement the `deinit` method in your classes:

> Swift **automatically** deallocates your instances when they are no longer
>   needed, to free up resources. Swift handles the memory management of
>   instances through automatic reference counting (ARC), as described in
>   Automatic Reference Counting. Typically *you don’t need to perform*
>   *manual cleanup when your instances are deallocated*. However, when you
>   are working with your own resources, you might need to perform some
>   additional cleanup yourself. For example, if you create a custom class
>   to open a file and write some data to it, you might need to close the
>   file before the class instance is deallocated.
>
> <sub>Swift Deinitialization Documentation - [How Deinitialization Works](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html) Section.</sub>

Usually, when working with View Controllers it seems that there is no need to do such an implementation. However, as mentioned in [@rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy)'s comment, it is still an approach for tracing memory leak or reference cycle with the view controller.

If your purpose is to check if the controller has been removed from the hierarchy (view controller life cycle), you could implement [*viewWillDisappear(_:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear)  or [*viewDidDisappear(_:)*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621477-viewdiddisappear) methods; Note that calling on of these methods does *not* guarantees that the `deinit` will be called, i.e it does not mean that disappearing the view controller always leads to deallocate it (related: [Deinit never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26971415/deinit-never-called), [explanation for deinit not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41772225/explanation-for-deinit-not-called)).

**Also:**

these Q&As should be useful:

- [When should I use deinit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24018758/when-should-i-use-deinit)
- [how to make deinit take effect in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38022278/how-to-make-deinit-take-effect-in-swift)
- [Understand deinitialization and inheritance in swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24019652/understand-deinitialization-and-inheritance-in-swift-language)

Comment: tl;dr - yes, using `deinit` is one way to verify you don't have a memory leak or reference cycle with the view controller.

Answer (score 1):

Swift automatically deallocates your instances when they are no longer needed, to free up resources. So to add `deinit` on all your `viewControllers` seems unnecessary. You should call `deinit` whenever you need to do some action or cleanup before deallocating an object.

Answer (score 1):

Well during the tests phase it maybe good idea, because you can check if everything is good (eg. if you have a lot of completion handler) but overall it is unnecessary.